backdrop-filter: blur() and mix-blend-mode: difference bug on Firefox
I'm working on a fixed footer that uses mix-blend-mode: difference to adjust to background changing from black to white. Also added the backdrop-filter: blur() as the "background".
On Chrome everything looks fine, however upon testing on Firefox this two don't mix together, they work fine on their own but not together. Is this a bug or intentional?
You can test it on this codepen
<div class="background">
  <div class="card card1">
  </div>
  <div class="card card2">
  </div>
  <div class="card card3">
  </div>
</div>


.background {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540959733332-eab4deabeeaf?q=80&w=2094&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.card1 {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.card2 {
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

.card3 {
  /*Using the two works on Chrome but not on Firefox*/
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

Is there any way to work around this?
I've tried using them separately on different divs but they still don't work together.

TL;DR
It is most probably caused by different interpreters/engines, as it is not standard right now
Now I will elaborate:
Webkit and Gecko (engines for Chrome and Firefox, respectively) will work differently between one another in some cases.
This was a real pain in the ass back then when, in some cases, we had to write 2 different codes just so it would be compatible to IE, as it used its own not market standard engine. Anyway...
As it is not yet broadly adopted/implemented through all major browsers/engine, I would not rely on it.
- "So, where could I check it became reliable then?"
That is a good question! I usually test it myself like you're doing in the first place. But there are some comunity-driven fonts that you could take a look as well. See https://caniuse.com/, for example.
There are some tools like BrowserStack that makes this a lot less painful to test your code in different browsers instead of installing different browsers (and versions) in different environments. But it is paid tho...
